# How to evenly time fading transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, setinterval, fade

so I'm trying to create a simple slide show from scratch, and so far I was able to get full screen images to fade out and fade in infinetly, but for some odd reason using `setInterval(function(){fade(var)}, 3500);`didn't work, maybe someone can explain why the first and last images took way longer than 3,5 seconds to fade. Meanwhile, I was trying to solve that problem by implementing a callback function in the `fade()`. My example has four images, and they start fading out until it reaches image one, then don't fade out image one and start fading back in image two until image 4, and do this forever, here is my recent attempt to implement a callback function:

```
var i = 4;

$(document).ready(function(){
            fade(i, fade);
});

var fadeIN = false;
function fade(objectID, callbackfn){
    var fadeTime = 3500;
    if(!fadeIN){
        $("#slide-"+objectID).fadeOut(fadeTime);
        i--;
        if(i === 1) {
            fadeIN = true;
        }
    }
    else{
        i++;
        $("#slide-"+objectID).fadeIn(fadeTime);
        if(i === 4){
            fadeIN = false;
        }
    }
    if(arguments[1]){
        callbackfn(i);
    }
}
```

But that is not working, it fades out image 4, image 3 and stops on image 2. Maybe there is a way to evenly time the fading transitions using the `setIntervel()`, if so can someone tell me how? Appreciate any help.

Here is a JSFiddle to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/8kgc0chq/ it is not working tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the doc for [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

There is an optional argument `complete`:

> A function to call once the animation is complete.

Put the next animation in there, they too take a `complete` (callback) function.

```
$("#id").fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
    // code to execute after animation complete 
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I tried doing that already. Doesn’t work either, here is the way I tried doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/t1owbmhe/

Comment: I just didn't understand one thing, why `if (!nextSlide.length)` works? I mean, what should a SLide.lenght returns?

Comment: It returns the number of elements matched from `var nextSlide = $('.slide[data-slide=' + (++activeSlideNumber) + ']')`, then it evaluates it. If its a `0` or negative it evaluates to false, if positive it evaluates to true. Check this to learn about it: [Truthy and Falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Comment: I read the article and the doubt persists, where I see it, `nextSlide` holds a reference to one of the divs with class `.slide` and attribute `[data-slide=(i)]` So when you say `if (!nextSlide.length)` you are trying to get the length of a div? It makes it look like `nextSlide` is an array and not a div. That is very confusing, is there another way to write the same thing so I can better understand it?

Comment: No, that is a jquery object, it contains info about the select we made with `$('.slide[data-slide=' + (++activeSlideNumber) + ']')`. We can select more elements than one with this selector, just like we can target more elements with a css selector, that's why we have a `.length` prop in it. If you `console.log(nextSlide )`  you are going to see it.

Comment: Al right, I'll take a look at JQuery objects, that’s all very confusing because I just started studying JavaScript and JQuery yesterday, appreciate the help you've given me.

Comment: Sry, I'm new to stack overflow, I up voted all you replies, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it properly with javascript. Easy way fails after last element.

So here is my solution. Can it be improved further, I think yes.. But it does work now. And is future proof to some extent.

I cleaned up css and changed html structure a little.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8kgc0chq/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        realTimeHeight();
    });
    realTimeHeight();
    startSlides();
});


function startSlides() {
    var fadeTime = 1000,
        delay = 1300,
        i = 0,
        slides = $("#hero-slider > .slide"),
        len = slides.length;

    slides.hide();

    var pF = $('<div class="slide">'), pB = pF.clone();
    pF.attr('id', slides.eq(i).attr('id'));
    $('#hero-slider').prepend(pF).prepend(pB);
    setInterval(fadeThisIn, fadeTime + delay);

    function fadeThisIn() {
        pB.attr('id', pF.attr('id'));
        i = ++i % len;
        pF.hide().attr('id', slides.eq(i).attr('id')).fadeIn(fadeTime);
    }
}

function realTimeHeight() {
    var altura = $(window).height();
    $("#hero-slider").css("height", altura);
}
```

Comment: some other things: you hadn't included jquery from left side resources panel, brackets were missing, and realTimeHeight wasn't called. In jsfiddle you dont need document ready as all script is loaded after load event by default

Comment: Thanks for the tips with jsfiddle, as I was discussing with Stefan down there, I need to study JQuery objects, you seem to use them on your code as well. As for the code, I'm confused to what does pF and pB means?

Comment: I create two divs pF stands for Front panel and Back Panel is pB i use them to put pictures on them so right image shows up on top etc.

Comment: You can learn it from here http://code.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-jquery